# Remove the data after a certain characters in a string using php

Tags: php

```
$title=Canon PowerShot SX130IS 12.1 MP Digital Camera with 12x Wide 
Angle Optical Image Stabilized Zoom with 3.0-Inch LCDCanon PowerShot 
SX130IS 12.1 MP Digital Camera with 12x Wide Angle Optical Image 
Stabilized Zoom with 3.0-Inch LCD
```

Want output as:

```
$title = Canon PowerShot SX130IS
```

`Without`  use of `strpos` in php because there is a group of data on which positions are different for string.Hence want to remove the data after a pattern in which as a e.g. `after 12.1 MP` I want to remove everything.
So anyone can tell me what pattern I can write for it.
`e.g. 12.1 MP camera(red),14.1 MP camera(blue) many characters written after that to be removed of from it`
Please anyone give me the required pattern for it!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to handle different megapixels you could use something like this:

```
preg_replace('/\s\d+\.?\d*\sMP.*/', "", "Canon PowerShot SX130IS 15.4 MP Digital Camera blabla");
```

Another variation to also catch "...SX130IS/15.4 MP..." and "...15.4MP..." would be:

```
preg_replace('/(\s|\/)\d+\.?\d*\s?MP.*/', "", "Canon PowerShot SX130IS 15.4 MP Digital Camera blabla");
```

Comment: Thanks your solution is good but if in some values are like e.g 11MP camera blah blah than what to do if the value is as per 12.1 MP and 11MP than what to do?

Comment: @PrachiVaraiya, the code which tobifasc written above will detect any value before the MP so you not need to worry about that.

Comment: but in starting you wrote na space if instead of space '/' or '(' is included and  if we have to remove that also than what to write in pattern

Comment: Could you explain that further? Do you mean something like 12.1/MP or 12.1(MP)?

Answer (score 1):

This will return the strings value based on the MP position.

```
    function foo($title) {        
        $title_array = explode(' ',$title);
        foreach ($title_array as $key => $value) {
            if($value === "MP"){
                $title = implode(' ',array_slice($title_array, 0, $key));
                return $title;
            }
        }
    }

    foo($title);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list($result) = explode("MP", $title, 2);
$result[0] = 'Canon PowerShot SX130IS 12.1 MP'
```

Comment: I want to remove 12.1MP also and then onwards string and it is on number of data so based on strpos we cant do it because it would have changing strpos on every strings